# Nested newenvironment definitions, within a table

Tags: tables, macros, environments

I'm trying to define two environments, one to be used inside the other. The first is a section in a CV, the second a subsection (cvitem). The latter holds an unordered list (commented for now, to isolate the problem). The subsection should be a two-column, which I'm trying to create using a table, such that all subsections can be aligned together. The cvitem's are then the rows in this table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newenvironment{cvsection}[1]{
    { \Large \bf #1 }
    \hrule height 0.5pt
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{}L{.25\linewidth}L{.75\linewidth}@{}}
} {
    \end{tabular}
}

\newenvironment{cvitem}[4]{
    #3 \linebreak #4 & {\bf #1}, #2 \linebreak \\
    %\begin{itemize}
} {
    %\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{cvsection}{Education}
    \begin{cvitem}{xxx}{xx}{xx}{xx}
        %\item x
    \end{cvitem}
\end{cvsection}
\end{document}
```

When I rewrite the cvitem to a `newcommand`, the code compiles successfully. But because I want to insert a list, it should be an environment. I tried defining cvitem as a command and converting it to an environment using the `environ` package, but this resulted in the same errors.

Comment: Welcome, i am not a fan of those kinds of definitions for CVs. They are unneeded and just lead to confusion. Where is the code coming from?

Comment: Except for the column type, I wrote it. Is there another technique you can suggest to achieve the same?

Comment: For resumes, i would go for the full brutal method completely by hand -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae#A_customizable_Layout

Comment: In this case, that would lead to a lot of duplicate code, though. So you don't know how to resolve this issue I described in the question?

Comment: Aside: Do not use the old TeX font commands but the LaTeX ones (`\bfseries`) to avoid side effects.

Comment: You cannot use `itemize` in table cells. I guess you should use `\multicolumn` and if you need some kind of itemization, search for the keyword `tabitem` here on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot issue `&` in the group formed by the `cvitem` environment.

With `environ` and some `\aftergroup` trickery you can do it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newenvironment{cvsection}[1]
 {%
  {\Large\bfseries #1}\vskip3pt\hrule height 0.5pt
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{}L{.25\linewidth}L{.75\linewidth}@{}}
 }
 {\end{tabular}}

\NewEnviron{cvitem}[4]{%
  \xdef\cvitembody{%
    \unexpanded{#3\par#4 & {\bfseries #1}, #2\tabularnewline}%
    \noexpand\begin{itemize}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \noexpand\end{itemize}\noexpand\tabularnewline
  }%
  \aftergroup\cvitembody
}

\begin{document}

\begin{cvsection}{Education}
  \begin{cvitem}{xxx}{xx}{xx}{xx}
  \item x
  \end{cvitem}
\end{cvsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround, using commands instead of environments. I do not understand why this works, and the code in the original question doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newenvironment{cvsection}[1]{
    { \Large \bf #1 }
    \hrule height 0.5pt
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{}L{.25\linewidth}L{.75\linewidth}@{}}
} {
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\cvitembegin}[4]{
    #3 \linebreak #4 & 
    {\bf #1}, #2 \linebreak
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
}
\newcommand{\cvitemend}{
    \end{itemize}\\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{cvsection}{Education}
    \cvitembegin{xxx}{xx}{xx}{xx}
        \item x
    \cvitemend
\end{cvsection}
\end{document}
```